# Android OpenCV undistort image produces different results from a seemingly identical python implementation

Tags: python, opencv, android

We have a simple python routine that takes an image and undistorts it by calling cv2.fisheye.undistortImage(). It produces a result that is expected based on the input image and the supplied camera matrix.

I ported the python function to Android. When fed the same input image, the Android version does NOT produce the same result, and I am at a loss to understand why. Am I missing something in the port?

**The Python source (Works as expected)**

```
cx = 960 
cy = 540
val = 600   

K = np.array([[  val,     0.  ,  cx],
            [    0. ,   val   ,  cy],
            [    0. ,    0.   ,  1.  ]])

# zero distortion coefficients work well for this image
D = np.array([0., 0., 0., 0.])

# use Knew to scale the output
Knew = K.copy()
Knew[(0,1), (0,1)] = 0.4 * Knew[(0,1), (0,1)]

img = cv2.imread('fisheye_sample.jpg')

img_undistorted = cv2.fisheye.undistortImage(img, K, D=D, Knew=Knew)
cv2.imwrite('fisheye_sample_undistorted.jpg', img_undistorted)
```

Now, the python code ported to Android as follows:

**The Android port (Not producing expected results)**

```
float fishVal = 600.0f;
float cX = 960;
float cY = 540;
Mat K = new Mat(3, 3, CvType.CV_32FC1);
K.put(0, 0, new float[]{fishVal, 0, cX});
K.put(1, 0, new float[]{0, fishVal, cY});
K.put(2, 0, new float[]{0, 0, 1});

Mat D = new Mat(1, 4, CvType.CV_32FC1);
D.put(0, 0, new float[]{0, 0, 0, 0});

Mat Knew = K.clone();
Knew.put(0, 0, new float[]{fishVal * 0.4f, 0.0f, cX});
Knew.put(1, 0, new float[]{0.0f, fishVal * 0.4f, cY});
Knew.put(2, 0, new float[]{0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f});

Mat dst = new Mat(greyScaleMat.rows(), greyScaleMat.cols(), greyScaleMat.type());
Imgproc.undistort(greyScaleMat, dst, K, D, Knew);
```

Given a constant input, I'm expecting both implementations to produce the same output. This is NOT happening. The Python version does some undistortion, but the Android version appears to be ignoring some of the input parameters. Is there something wrong with my Android port that I'm not seeing?

**Input Image** 
[image]

**Python Output Image (Correct!)**
The below image was undistorted as expected
[image]
**Android output image (Incorrect!)**
When run through the Android function as described above, no undistortion was performed. Instead the image was scaled down as per the Knew matrix. Any ideas on how to explain this difference?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much head scratching, forum scouring and source code sleuthing, I found the answer.
It turns out that the implementation of `Imgproc.undistort()` is *not* the same as `cv2.fisheye.UndistortImage()`

The equivalent in the Java/JNI world is `Calib3d.undistortImage()`. When that function is called, the output is identical to the python version.

It was necessary to upgrade OpenCV for Android to a version higher than 3 to have access to this function.